# linux grep command is not returning accurate results

Tags: linux, bash, grep, redhat

grep command is not returning accurate results.

I have a text file which has some html content. I want to get the count of a specific word using the grep command.the grep command is not returning accurate results.OS - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

Below is the content of the input file's test.txt.
This file has two occurrences of the word "Tomcat" 


`<html><title>Tomcat Server</title><body><font face="Verdana, Arial" size="-1"><p>Tomcat Server</p></body></html>`

grep command

`cat test.txt|grep -c Tomcat`

`cat test.txt|grep -c "Tomcat"`


Note: It's the same result with or without quotes

Expected Result: count - 2

Actual Result: count - 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the difference between "accurate" and "desired." The `grep` man page says of the -c flag:

> Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for each input file.  With the -v, --invert-match option (see below), count  non-matching lines.

So it's counting that one line had a match, and that's what it tells you.

Comment: right. Those lucky people who have GNU grep, can you use `grep -o Tomcat | wc -l`